# Showing Error: Failed to get remote.origin.url when deploying react vite website using gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, npm, deployment, vite, github-pages

Error: Failed to get remote.origin.url (task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin remote or must be configured with the "repo" option).

Error when trying to deploy to github pages using gh-pages.
Git repo has a origin configured.

It worked correctly on windows and I deployed the changes a few times, but now I am using linux mint and it is not working on it.

- I used -r option with gh-option and the error is still showing
- I also tried removing and adding origin remote but no change
- Also tried to initialize a git repo ahain and cloning all the files to it and use gh-pages -d dist but still no change